# friend url on wildcard subdomains htacces, not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have wildcard subdomains sets already and works fine, now i wish have friends url for the content in thats subdomains, the structure of my site is if the user type subdomain.maindomain.com and the .htaccess redirect to

```
blogs/index.php?user=subdomain
```

where blogs/index.php receive the param and show the correct content

now i try to make the url function like this

```
subdomain.maindoamin.com/24/title-of-content
```

and then .htaccess must result

```
blogs/index.php?id_content=24&title=title-of-content
```

i have the next .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

#this force to server the content always without www.
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301]

#this is to pass the subdomain like param and show the right content of the user
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.misite\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9]+)\.misite\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blogs/index.php?url=%1 [QSA,L]

#the next line i can't make work to make nice url
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)$ blogs/index.php?idP=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

not working because when i make in index.php

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

don't show idP=24 show /24/title-of-content and i need $_GET(idP)

i really apreciate some light on this stuff i am not expert on htaccess, thanks in advance to everybody.

Comment: Please read [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule). Especially the part that says *"•The removed prefix always ends with a slash, meaning the matching occurs against a string which never has a leading slash. Therefore, a Pattern with ^/ never matches in per-directory context."*

Comment: Also `RewriteRule`'s are executed in the order they appear. The second rule will always match in the cases you want to match the third one. Switch the two, so the more specific one is first.

Comment: hi! thanks already read the link you give me, so my htaccess have a new RewriteCond RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/(.*)$ [NC] RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ blogs/index.php?idP=$1&name=$2 [QSA] but still dont work, what i am doing wrong? also i remove the [L] for the second rule, i am make test with this tool http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: also i change the second rule like this RewriteRule ^(.*)\.misite\.com$ blogs/index.php?url=%1 [QSA] but the wildcard subdomain no work anymore.

Comment: `%{REQUEST_URI}` starts with a slash, and the first argument of `RewriteRule` can't be used to match the domain name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. The first argument of `RewriteRule` matches against everything after the slash of the directory `.htaccess` is in, and before the query string. If `.htaccess` is in your www-root, and you get the url `http://www.example.com/shiny/unicorns.php?are=shiny`, you match against `shiny/unicorns.php`. It will never start with a slash, so `^/` will never match.
2. Rules are executed in order. If you go to `http://sub.example.com/10/unicorns`, the second rule will match first and rewrite the request to `/blogs/index.php?url=10/unicorns`. If you removed the leading slash the third rule would match, but normally you wouldn't want that. You want to have the third rule only match

You want to move the third rule up so it is the second rule. You want to make it more specific to only match with subdomains. You also know the first part contains only numbers, so use that knowledge to prevent `blogs/index.php` from matching your *now* second rule. You also need to prevent blogs/index.php from matching the *now* third rule to prevent it from matching itself. Last but not least I removed `[L]` from the *now* second rule, since the third rule will match anyway.

```
#the next line i can't make work to make nice url
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([^/]+)$ blogs/index.php?idP=$1&name=$2

#this is to pass the subdomain like param and show the right content of the user
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.misite\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9]+)\.misite\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/blogs/index\.php
RewriteRule ^ blogs/index.php?url=%1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: thank you very much Sumurai8, this is the first time i have to deal with complex htaccess, yes change the level the rules work, your solution work excellente, thank you very much, is there some documentation you recommend me to learn more of the rules of rewrite on htaccess? thanks again